# Issue with Google Shopping plugin outputting massive arrays

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, google-shopping

I'm working on integrating Google Shopping with my Magento installation but have ran into an issue with the plugin (provided by https://github.com/bluevisiontec/GoogleShoppingApi)

The plugin works great on our UK counterpart, but on the US environment

```
<?php echo $this->getAttributesSelectHtml(true) ?>
```

(located at /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/googleshoppingapi/types/edit/attributes.phtml) causes large (approximately 40mb) to be output. I've look at the function inside the relevant block and can't seem to find anything wrong.

The server is a newly configured environment running Magento 1.9.1 with PHP 5.4. I encountered the same issue in the old environment we were using, hence changing.